# Como organizar uma lista de números em uma sequência de maior, menor, maior, menor... - Python

Tags: python, random

Estou implementando uma funcionalidade de shuffle, e gostaria de saber se há algum jeito mais fácil do que essa gambiarra feia que fiz

Ele funciona, exceto caso tenha um número 0 na lista de músicas tocadas, quebra total.

```
musicas_tocadas = [2, 10, 5, 3] # lista default
# shuffle = [10, 2, 5, 3] resultado que preciso
```

```
def shuffle_musicas(musicas_tocadas):
    shuffle = []
    mais_tocada = max(musicas_tocadas)
    shuffle.append(mais_tocada)
    mais_pos = musicas_tocadas.index(mais_tocada)

    menos_tocada = min(musicas_tocadas)
    shuffle.append(menos_tocada)
    menos_pos = musicas_tocadas.index(menos_tocada)

    for delete in range(len(musicas_tocadas)):
        musicas_tocadas[mais_pos] = 0
        musicas_tocadas[menos_pos] = 0
        mais_tocada = max(musicas_tocadas)
        shuffle.append(mais_tocada)
        mais_pos = musicas_tocadas.index(mais_tocada)
        menos_tocada = min(musicas_tocadas)
        shuffle.append(menos_tocada)
        menos_pos = musicas_tocadas.index(menos_tocada)

    aux = list(dict.fromkeys(shuffle))

        zero = aux.index(0)
        aux.pop(zero)

    return(aux)
```

Comment: Primeiro ordene a lista. Depois, construa a lista nova pegando o último elemento, depois o primeiro, o penúltimo, o segundo, e assim por diante... E só pra ser chato, isso não é *shuffle* (pois "shuffle" significa "embaralhar", mas vc não está embaralhando, está colocando em uma ordem específica, com regras bem definidas) :-)

Comment: fiz isso mesmo, foi o jeito ashduashudasd, obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

confesso que nem entendi qual o seu objetivo, mas olhando o resultado que você quer, e o comentario do hkotsubo, você poderia fazer o seguinte (da pra melhorar isso):

```
musicas_tocadas = [2, 10, 5, 3]

# faz uma copia da lista, e ordena em ordem crescente
musicas_ordenadas = musicas_tocadas.copy()
musicas_ordenadas.sort()

# resultado final
shuffle = []

# faz um loop ate acabar todos os elementos da lista
while True:
    try:
        # remove o ultimo elemento da lista e adiciona na lista shuffle
        shuffle.append(musicas_ordenadas.pop(-1))

        # remove o primeiro elemento da lista e adiciona na lista shuffle
        shuffle.append(musicas_ordenadas.pop(0))


    # já percorreu toda a lista (lista vazia)
    except IndexError:
        break


print(shuffle)
```

Comment: Em vez de copiar a lista, pode fazer apenas `musicas_ordenadas = sorted(musicas_tocadas)` pois `sorted` já retorna uma cópia da lista, sem alterar a original